# SQL dedupe based on number of matching columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to find info on how to dedupe a table based upon the number of matching columns between records.

Let's say my data source looks like

```
---------------------------------------------------
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnN |
---------------------------------------------------
| Peter   | Dink    | Midget  | NULL    | 0738455 |
| Peter   | Dink    | Child   | 334AA   | 49595   |
| Mark    | Walhg   | Funky   | 334AA   | 0738455 | 
| Mark    | Dink    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| Mark    | Walhg   | Funky   | 334AA   | NULL    |
| Peter   | Dink    | NULL    | NULL    | 0738455 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Basically I want to be able to offer a count of records that share 2, 3, 4, etc columns of data; however I need this constrained to only a select subset of columns (and ignore NULL/blanks).

From the data above I would want to be able to say:

1. There are 0 records that match on 5 columns
2. There are 1 records that match on 4 columns (3,5)
3. There are 1 records that match on 3 columns (1,6) (3,5)
4. There are 2 records that match on 2 columns (1,6) (2,6) (3,5) (1,2)

I would also need it to like "shift" down as the number of matched columns becomes less and less. So in the above my data is the same after checking for a match of 5 columns. Then on 4 columns the data is reduced to:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnN |
---------------------------------------------------
| Peter   | Dink    | Midget  | NULL    | 0738455 |
| Peter   | Dink    | Child   | 334AA   | 49595   |
| Mark    | Walhg   | Funky   | 334AA   | 0738455 | 
| Mark    | Dink    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| Peter   | Dink    | NULL    | NULL    | 0738455 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

The 5th column is gone because it's been deduped (I have no idea how I decided which was removed, probably on some date column). So I can say 1 record is removed.

After the check on 3 columns:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnN |
---------------------------------------------------
| Peter   | Dink    | Midget  | NULL    | 0738455 |
| Peter   | Dink    | Child   | 334AA   | 49595   |
| Mark    | Walhg   | Funky   | 334AA   | 0738455 | 
| Mark    | Dink    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
---------------------------------------------------
```

So I can say another 1 is removed.

Then 2 columns:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnN |
---------------------------------------------------
| Peter   | Dink    | Midget  | NULL    | 0738455 |
| Mark    | Walhg   | Funky   | 334AA   | 0738455 | 
| Mark    | Dink    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Another column is removed.

The way I thought I would approach it is by giving a weight that's essentially the number of matching data points from a selection of the columns. For example, maybe I wouldn't want to use the Country column to count as one of the matching columns, I would only use things that identify the record like Name and Phone Number.

Then I can look at how many records are deduped at each weight (number of column matches) and make a decision that we will dedupe everything with 7 matching columns of identity data; and roll up any values in one record that are NULL/blank in it's duplicate record.

This is all very beyond me. I know what I want to do; just have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understood you correctly. This is my idea of how this can be done, its not complete you can automate it more with dynamic sql and a while loop to go trough all of the ids and to unify the results later on.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TestTable1') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE TestTable1

CREATE TABLE TestTable1 (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ColumnA NVARCHAR(100),
    ColumnB NVARCHAR(100),
    ColumnC NVARCHAR(100),
    ColumnD NVARCHAR(100),
    ColumnE INT
)

INSERT INTO TestTable1 VALUES 
('Peter','Dink','Milk',NULL,0738455),
('Peter','Dink','Beer','334AA',49595),
('Mark','Walk','Funky','334AA',0738455),
('Mark','Dink',NULL,NULL,NULL),
('Mark','Walk','Funky','334AA',NULL),
('Peter','Dink',NULL,NULL,0738455)

DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = 1

SELECT * FROM TestTable1 WHERE ID IN 
(
    SELECT ID FROM
    (   
        SELECT @ID AS ID
        UNION
        SELECT b.ID FROM TestTable1 as a
        CROSS APPLY TestTable1 as b
        WHERE a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA
        AND a.ID = @ID AND b.ID <> @ID
    ) AS OneMatchingColumn
) 


SELECT * FROM TestTable1 WHERE ID IN 
(
    SELECT ID FROM
    (
        SELECT @ID AS ID
        UNION
        SELECT b.ID FROM TestTable1 as a
        CROSS APPLY TestTable1 as b
        WHERE a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA
        AND a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB
        AND a.ID = @ID AND b.ID <> @ID
    ) AS TwoMatchingColumns
)


SELECT * FROM TestTable1 WHERE ID IN 
(
    SELECT ID FROM
    (
        SELECT @ID AS ID
        UNION
        SELECT b.ID FROM TestTable1 as a
        CROSS APPLY TestTable1 as b
        WHERE a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA
        AND a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB
        AND a.ColumnC = b.ColumnC
        AND a.ID = @ID AND b.ID <> @ID
    ) AS ThreeMatchingColumns
)
```

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind. Using the above I can loop and find records that match each record based on any two matching columns (with a little change + addition). However, once I have this I'm not sure how I would amalgamate all the results?

Comment: You can put them in variable tables, temp tables, original tables, views, make a procedure which you write the name of the table and columns you want to dedupe.. something like that :P